# Cannot find module '@/components/my-components' in React Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am creating a React app using Next.js and app routing. I'd like to create a separate file to hold the custom components I am creating. I noticed [this Vercel template app](https://github.com/vercel-labs/ai-chatbot/tree/main/components) does this using a `components/` directory and then importing the components in the app using declarations like `import { Chat } from '@/components/chat'`

So, I created a components/ folder as well, giving me this file tree:

```
.
├── components /
│   └── my-components.tsx
└── src /
    └── app/
        └── page.tsx
```

However, when I try `import {Component} from '@/components/my-components';` in `page.tsx`, I get the error: `Module not found: Can't resolve '@/components/my-components'`

How can I debug this further?

I also tried importing via path, e.g. `import {Component} from './../../../components/my-components';` but that didn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@/` import alias is defined in your `tsconfig.json` file by the `compilerOptions.paths` key.

If `@/components/my-components` doesn't work for you, it's because `@/` is an alias for a folder other than your root folder. A common value used for this in Next.js projects is `./src/*` which would mean TypeScript is trying to find your component at `./src/components/my-component`.

Answer (score 0):

The `components` folder should also be located under the `src` folder.

see in https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/src-directory

> If you're using src, you'll probably also move other application folders such as /components or /lib.

Comment: This is just a recommendation, but it isn't necessary. The problem here is the TypeScript `paths` import alias.

Answer (score 0):

So, this happens to me too a lot. What I do is delete the import and then click on the element where I'm using it. Then hit CTRL+SPACE and it will import it at the top and works just fine. I do not understand the reason for this considering the text is exactly the same. If you are using something like:

```
<AppBar>
```

just click anywhere inside the element and hit CTRL+Space and it should prompt you to import it from wherever it is in your project.